# I'm trying to write conditionals for my program

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements, command-line-interface

I am running a program where I want the use to be able to select 1-28 and the program will `print_details`. However if the user types in ANYTHING else I want to print an error.

UPDATED CODE

```
 input = gets.strip
     if input.to_i.between?(0, 27)
      print_details(gets.strip)
      puts "Is there another episode you would like details on? Y/N".cyan

      input = gets.strip
      if input == "Y"
         list_episode
         list_menu
      elsif input == "y"
         list_episode
         list_menu
      elsif input == "N"
       bye
      elsif input == "n"
       bye
     else
      puts "That is not a valid input".red
      list_menu
     end
```

Not sure if I missed something? I noticed that if I input "88" it exits my program and if I type "a" it prints that last episode details.

Comment: You set first `input` to something which (hopefully) will be a number between 0 and 27, then you ask a second time something from stdin and run `puts_details` on it, finally you throw away the value entered in the beginning by asking a third time something from stdin and store it on `input`. What effect is this supposed to have????

Comment: Please post [mcve] using stubs for methods required for the code to run.

Comment: If you want to ensure you are getting a whole number (`Integer`) I would recommend `input = Integer(gets.strip)`. You will have to handle the error that arises from non-integer entries. [This Article](https://medium.com/rubycademy/error-handling-in-ruby-part-i-557898185e2f) offers a reasonable explanation for how to go about that